# I need replace placeholder with image

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I have PDF document with some images and one placeholder where I have to put image. My problem is that the image always has size of placeholder when i run program. Where I am wrong? 
Image size is (320x120).

```
    PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(pdfDocumentBase64);
    PDImageXObject editObject =LosslessFactory.createFromImage(pdfDocument, signatureImage);
    PDPageTree list = pdfDocument.getPages();
    pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
    for (PDPage page : list) {
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();

        for (COSName name : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {

            PDImageXObject o = (PDImageXObject) pdResources.getXObject(name);


            if (o instanceof PDImageXObject && o.getHeight() < 100) {

                int a = o.getWidth(); //  10 --- placeholder
                int b = o.getHeight(); // 10 ---- placeholder

                pdResources.put(name,editObject);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: À la PdfStamper you can overwrite the page with the image as addition at the location of the placeholder.

Comment: Is there any example of code for this problem, because there can be more then one placeholder. How I can resize existing image (10x10, placeholder) on size image. I try with _o.setWidth(imageWidth);_  and  _o.setHeight(imageHeight);_ but not working

Comment: Is this about pdfbox or about itext?

Comment: Please, do you have any advice on how to handle this?

Comment: The size of the image as displayed is controlled by the current transformation matrix value at the instruction of drawing the image. If you want to change those dimension, you have to change the page content stream (or xobject or pattern or... content stream) in question.

Comment: Can you give me some example of that? please

Comment: How can i resize the placeholder (image) in pdf document. Is that possible?

Comment: `PDPageContentStream.drawImage()` has parameters that influence the size.

Comment: Thanks, but i need x, y coordinates to replace placeholder with my image.

Comment: See the `PrintImageLocations.java` example in the source code download.

Comment: Solved! Thanks guys.

Comment: Please delete the question or answer it yourself, I don't even know what the exact problem / roadblock was.

Comment: If I have some text instead of image (placeholder) how i can replace string text with image?